# How to efficiently apply cumprod to all columns in the tidyverse

Tags: r, performance, tidyverse

I have a large-ish random matrix (either 500 x 100,000 or 500 by 10,000) and I want to apply cumprod to every column. On the 500 x 10,000 my code runs in 13 seconds. On the 500 x 100,000 it runs in 32 minutes. Is there a more efficient or better scaling way than the below to do this within the tidyverse?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mc2d)

n.rows = 500  #Number of times
n.cols = 100000  #Number of samples
outcomes = as_tibble(matrix(1 + ifelse(rbern(n.rows * n.cols, .5), .5, -.4), 
                            nrow = n.rows)) %>% 
  modify(cumprod)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, an option is `across` to loop over the columns

```
out2 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), cumprod))
```

-checking with OP's output

```
out1 <- df1 %>%
         modify(cumprod)

identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

If it is still slow, then can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, (seq_along(df1)) := lapply(.SD, cumprod)]
```

#### Benchmarks

Using the bigger data, an option is also use `lapply`

```
n.rows <- 500  #Number of time
n.cols <- 100e3  #Number of samples

raw_data  <- as_tibble(matrix(1 + ifelse(rbern(n.rows * n.cols, .5), .5, -.4), nrow = n.rows))


system.time({out = raw_data %>% map_df(cumprod)})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.819   0.125   1.943 
system.time({raw_data[] <- lapply(raw_data, cumprod)})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.432   0.088   0.520
```

#### data

```
df1 <- as_tibble(matrix(1 + ifelse(rbern(n.rows * n.cols, .5), .5, -.4), 
                         nrow = n.rows))
```

Comment: That's impressive with just a simple `lapply`! I have no clue why the `data.table` approach is much slower than the `lapply` one, although they seems follows the same method

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding there would be backlog of attributes in data.frame/tibble that slows down.  I think `map` s fairly fast.  May be, it would be better to check with `set` as well

Comment: Okey, I see. `data.table` cannot be the winner of all the time :P

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding It may depend on the criteria OP used.  If you check the number of rows, it is very small, but the number of cols are way bigger.  Usually, we check with the reverse

Answer (score 1):

If you fixed number of rows for your `tibble` data, you actually can use `Reduce` to implement `cumprod`, which seems a faster option

```
do.call(rbind, Reduce("*", asplit(df, 1), accumulate = TRUE))
```

**Benchmark** (thank [@akrun's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65450265/12158757) for this)

```
> system.time({
+   out1 <- do.call(rbind, Reduce("*", asplit(df, 1), accumulate = TRUE))
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   6.55    0.22    6.76

> system.time({
+   out2 <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, cumprod)]
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  44.93    0.02   45.01

> all.equal(out1, as.matrix(out2))
[1] TRUE
```

where the dummy data `df` is given as

```
set.seed(1)
nr <- 500
df <- as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(5e7), nr), nrow = nr)
```

Comment: That solution using Reduce is very interesting. But seems to be an undocumented use of Reduce! I don't see anywhere in the documentation what Reduce is supposed to do applies to a list of vectors. Instead, all documentation talks about it being applied to a 1-dimension object like a list *or* a vector.

Comment: @blabber-blue This may help you understand better on `Reduce` https://blog.zhaw.ch/datascience/r-reduce-applys-lesser-known-brother/

Comment: @ ThomasIsCoding That was actually one of the articles I read after seeing your use of Reduce. But the semantics of your use don't seem to be covered there as far as I can tell. You are applying Reduce to a list of arrays. Each array is a **row** of the original data frame. In that situation, I would have guessed Reduce would have applied `*` along **rows** not along **columns**! And I see nothing in that article or any other documentation which would have allowed me to predict what Reduce did.

Comment: @blabber-blue In the list of arrays, you begin with running `*` over the first two arrays, and the product is also an array. Then, the produced array will be element-wisely multiplied with the third array, so on and so forth. `Reduce` is applicable to a list of anything (scalars, arrays, data.frame, and etc) as long as they are following the same operation (here is `*` in your post).

Comment: Of course! I was thinking of * taking two scalars not two arrays. I was being dumb. Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 1):

I benchmarked a bunch of solutions. @ThomaslsCoding's solution was the fastest of those offered but I seem to have found a simpler and equally fast solution-- the use of map_df.

```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(mc2d)
> library(data.table)
> 
> n.rows = 500  #Number of time
> n.cols = 100e3  #Number of samples
> 
> raw_data = as_tibble(matrix(1 + ifelse(rbern(n.rows * n.cols, .5), .5, -.4), nrow = n.rows))
> 
> system.time({out = raw_data %>% modify(cumprod)})
    user   system  elapsed 
1184.269   21.915 1207.873 
> system.time({out = raw_data %>% mutate(across(everything(), cumprod))})
    user   system  elapsed 
3495.240   15.792 3516.903 
> system.time({out = setDT(raw_data)[, lapply(.SD, cumprod)]})
   user  system elapsed 
 48.245   0.280  48.745 
> system.time({out = do.call(rbind, Reduce("*", asplit(raw_data, 1), accumulate = TRUE))})
   user  system elapsed 
  2.099   0.127   2.230 
> system.time({out = raw_data %>% map_df(cumprod)})
   user  system elapsed 
  1.306   0.008   1.316
```

**NEW TESTS BELOW**

```
> system.time({out = do.call(rbind, Reduce("*", asplit(raw_data, 1), accumulate = TRUE))})
   user  system elapsed 
  1.777   0.032   1.814 
> system.time({out = raw_data %>% map_df(cumprod)})
   user  system elapsed 
  1.393   0.012   1.410 
> system.time({out[] = lapply(raw_data, cumprod)})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.278   0.003   0.282 
> system.time({out = apply(raw_data, 2, cumprod)})
   user  system elapsed 
  1.126   0.012   1.142
```

lapply is fastest for me too

Comment: I'm trying to learn some general lessons from this exercise. How could one have guessed a-priori that the ```Reduce``` solution would be faster than the ```modify``` solution? Shouldn't ```cumprod``` be more optimized than ```Reduce("*", accumulate = 1)```? And shouldn't modify be more optimized than using ```do.call``` with ```rbind```? Finally, how could one have guessed that ```map_df``` would be faster than ```modify``` when doing the job of ```modify```? This seems to be an undocumented use of ```map_df````. The documentation says  the function is supposed to return a scalar.

Comment: Can you also try with `raw_data[] <- lapply(raw_data, cumprod)` should be faster

Comment: I added the use of lapply and just plain apply. This is part of my frustration with R. Why does lapply work faster for applying to columns than apply with MARGIN = 2 when that is the intended purpose of apply? And I still have no idea why modify is so slow when its documented purpose is to apply along columns. Is there any framework for understanding these results or does one need to try everything under the sun and just see what's fastest empirically?

Comment: And of course we're now far outside the tidyverse. I know base R reasonably well (although clearly didn't properly understand Reduce!). I'm trying to learn tidyverse well enough to operate efficiently there without having to resort to base R. Although admittedly that's just kind of the purist in me. You have to just do what works in rate-determining steps...